# Quantum Computing Beta is up and running!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Hello Computer Science users! I'm here to announce that the [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) site is open to join. Your expertise would be very welcome as we continue building our new site.

We accept those who are interested in quantum computing, studying, experts, and interested in everything from programming quantum computers to creating quantum algorithms to actually building them. We already have a decent question and user base and activity is rather high for a beta site, so we hope that you'll come on over and enjoy yourselves!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75095/discussion-on-question-by-heather-quantum-computing-beta-is-up-and-running).